# How to change 'CachePath' of RequestContext at runtime?

Tags: browser-cache, cefsharp

I looked it up everywhere on internet where I could not find how to find any code snippets for changing the 'CachePath' of RequestContext at runtime. I need this because I need to enable and disable Incognito mode of CefSharp browser as a user action. Can someone share the snippet with me here.

Answer (score 0):

Not supported. `CachePath` is effectively immutable, once it's set it cannot be changed.